# Stop image repeating after viewing all list in jQuery Carousel in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jcarousel

nextgen-jquery-carousel plugin for wordpress to display horizontally a list of images. I want that after viewing the list the carousel to stop from browsing from the beginning. Can I do that?
For example I would like an arrow to hide after viewing all the images.

Answer (score 0):

Is it using [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jj-nextgen-jquery-carousel/) plugin? If so, you can check out [this page](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration) that will show you all the parameters you can set. It looks like you want to use the "wrap" parameter.

If you implemented [this](http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm) jCarousel,  you would use the "loop" parameter.